# Listar BLOG e mostrar na mesma página o ARTIGO escolhido

Tags: php, array, funções, url-amigável, breadcrumbs

Estou trabalhando com PHP e utilizo URL amigável.
Ao clicar no link `<a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo URL::getBase(); ?>blog" tabindex="12">blog</a>`, minha URL fica:

> http://127.0.0.1/rogarfil.com.br/blog

Abrindo a página `blog.php` esta contém a função `function getBlog()` que lista todos os artigos, com uma paginação de 10 por página.

Ao clicar em um destes artigos, minha URL fica:

> http://127.0.0.1/rogarfil.com.br/artigo/63/ti/minha-empresa-precisa-de-website

Abrindo a página `artigo.php` esta contém a função:

```
function getViewBlog() {  
    // Ler URL (array)  
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  
    $valor = explode("/", $url);  
    // Recebe o id do rgf_content via GET  
    $id_blog = $valor[3];
    ...
}
```

Onde pega o `id_blog` da URL e mostra todo o conteúdo deste artigo nesta página.

O que estou buscando realizar é fazer com que estas duas funções abram na mesma página que aqui neste caso seria a `blog.php`.

> HOME > ROGARFIL.COM.BR > ARTIGO > 63 > TI > MINHA EMPRESA PRECISA DE WEBSITE

O motivo que leva-me a essa lógica é que da maneira que se encontra e quando estou na página `artigo.php` e ao clicar no link do breadcrumbs em artigo surge o erro:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\rogarfil.com.br\src\includes\files\functions.php on line 326

Pois na URL não aparece o conteúdo da variável `$id_blog`.

Answer (score -1):

A página blog ficou desta forma e resolvido:

// Ler URL (array)
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$valor = explode("/", $url);

if (isset($valor[3])) {

`<!-- Blog Grid -->
<section id="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 mt-3">
            <?php getViewBlog();?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section><!-- /.Blog Grid -->`

} else {

`<!-- Blog Grid -->
<section id="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 mt-3">
            <h1 class="display-5 text-uppercase"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o text-info" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;blog&nbsp;</h1>
            <p class="lead text-info text-uppercase" >artigo&nbsp;sobre&nbsp;ti,&nbsp;programa&ccedil;&atilde;o,&nbsp;cria&ccedil;&atilde;o&nbsp;&&nbsp;acad&ecirc;micos</p>
            <hr class="linha" />
            <?php getBlog();?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section><!-- /.Blog Grid -->`
}

Comment: bastou utilizar o isset na condicional if